# Error when record is added to table programmatically vba access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-insert

I am trying to add a record to a table on MouseUp(), but it gives me the following error:
https://imagebin.ca/v/3ZDGpjhINaCs

I am unsure as to why. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnSignup_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
TempVars!newMember = Me.MemberID.Value

    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Signup VALUES (TempVars!newMember, TempVars!currentStaffMember)"

End Sub
```

Here is the line that the debugger stops on:

https://imagebin.ca/v/3ZDHvAvBfM7b

Signup Table:
https://imagebin.ca/v/3ZDL9vo20UQL

Comment: What does the Signup table look like? You're probably not populating all the required fields.

Comment: There seems to be a key on the first column. Make sure you're not trying to insert duplicate values. As a test, insert a mock value that doesn't exist anywhere and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Please provide the error also. Note that the preferred way of sharing images on StackOverflow is the built-in imgur in the question form, not imagebin, since imgur will keep the images online as long as the question is.